# AWS lambda not processing S3 file fast enough

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My requirement is to process files that gets created in S3 and stream the content of the file to SQS queue which will be consumed by other processes.

When a new files gets created in the S3 bucket, notification is published to SQS queue which triggers the lambda and the lambda written in Python process the file and publishes the content to SQS queue. File size at max is 100 MB so it might have 300K message but it is being processed very slow. I am not sure where the problem is, I have set the lambda memory limit to 10 GB and runtime to 15 mins. also I have set the concurrency limit to 100

S3---->SQS--->lambda-->SQS

I have the set the visibility timeout to 30 mins for the message; the processing is so slow that it moves the file creation message to dead letter queue.

Comment: Is the Lambda function taking a long time to run? Or is the Lambda function just not picking up the items from the queue fast enough? Are you dropping files in the bucket faster than the 100 concurrent Lambda invocations can handle them? What are your Lambda SQS integration settings? You need to provide more information, and ideally do some due-diligence to determine where the bottleneck is, before anyone can really give you an answer.

Comment: I see lambda running for 15 mins. I am not sure how exactly a function is invoked by aws Lambda. When I set the batch size to 10 messages, does a Lambda picks up 10 message from the queue and keeps calling the same function 10 times to process all the message. In my case the lambda is triggered by S3 file created event. If the batch 10 message are processed by same Lambda in a sequence, does the time limit of 15 mins apply to per function invocation or for processing of all message batch.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing because you make reference to SQS twice, and it isn't clear whether you are referencing two separate SQS queues, or the same queue. Also, when you say that "it is being processed very slow", you are not providing any evidence -- have you used `print` statements to track the progress of the task and then looked in CloudWatch Logs to see where the time is being consumed? It might be slow processing your input file, or it might be slow processing the messages from the second SQS queue -- please test this, then Edit your question to show the results.

Comment: Lambda reads from one queue and publishes to a separate queue. I see this error 'Task timed out after 900.10 seconds'. That is why I am trying to understand how Lambda max run time get applied, so when we have a batch of 10 messages, does the Lambda run time gets applied per function call or for 10 function calls. I am assuming that my issue is caused by time out.when Lambda picks up 10 message, each file create event so it has to process 10 files. I think some calls get timed out in the middle of file processing and the msg is put back to queue and reprocessed again.

Comment: The timeout is for the lambda execution. The timeout setting doesn't care about how many messages are processed. Regardless that 100M should be read and processed in a few seconds, so some profiling (measuring what takes what time) could be helpful. If you're creating A LOT of small sqs messages from the content, you could consider using the `SendMessageBatch` operation sending multiple. messages with a single call

Answer (score 0):

It will take somewhere between 10 and 50 milliseconds to write a single message to SQS. If you have 300,000 messages that you're trying to write in a single Lambda invocation, then that's 3,000 seconds in the best case, which is larger than the Lambda timeout.

Once the Lambda times out, any SQS messages that it was processing will go back on the queue, and delivered against once their visibility timeout expires.

You can try multi-threading the code that writes messages to SQS. Since it's mostly network IO, you should be able to scale linearly up to a dozen or so threads. That may, however, just mean that your downstream message handlers get overloaded.

Also, reduce your batch size to 1. SQS will invoke multiple Lambdas if there are more messages in the queues.

Comment: Should be sending 10 messages at a time, not 1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html

Comment: That's a good additional point, if the OP is not already batching messages.